# SSRS Expression to Filter and then Count

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2019

I have a large query that each record has a unique WO Number and a division. I would like to use an expression in the text box to give me a number of unique work orders with a specific division.

Example:

```
Dataset name: CorrectiveWOsOPEN

WO_NUMBER  DIVISION
20-005802  Maintenance
20-005803  Maintenance
20-014771  Maintenance
20-027196  PCA
20-027197  Water
20-027198  Water
18-005079  Water
18-005541  Water
```

Desired Result for filter for 'Water" division and count the number of records:

```
4
```

I got the count expression but not know how to attach on the filter for "Water" in division column.

```
=Count(Fields!WO_NUMBER.Value, "CorrectiveWOsOPEN")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: off the top of my head, you could create a group that filters by division=water and use the group name in your count()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an IIF inside a sum to count the ones with your desired filter.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!DIVISION.Value = "Water", 1, 0), "CorrectiveWOsOPEN")
```

This will check each record for a Division of **Water** and return 1 if it is and zero if not and then sums these up.

I suppose you could also do the same with COUNT and NOTHING but I think the former method is more elegant (for lack of a better word).

```
=COUNT(IIF(Fields!DIVISION.Value = "Water", Fields!WO_NUMBER.Value, NOTHING), "CorrectiveWOsOPEN")
```